# MOSS sends two emails when a workflow is enabled

Tags: sharepoint-workflow

Perspective: I do not have access to SharePoint Designer, the ivory tower believes its for IT folk only. All the fixes I've read on the site are for people with access to Designer, so I'm reaching out for an alternative solution.

SO, I have a list that kicks off an approval workflow when a new item is added. My issue is that I receive 2 emails: one almost instantly from moss@mycompany.com. The second comes in a minute or two later from Forms

I've been up and down the workflow settings to try to get only a singular note. Is there something in my control that I can change? I fear that two emails will confuse users.

The first email contains the " has started on " verbiage.
The second email contains the "Task assigned by  on . It also has two attachments (consistently) that are just regurgitations of the main body email.

Any assistance is surely appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

The reason why I was getting two emails was because I was setting myself as an **approver** as well.

The initial email was hey requestor (me) a new workflow was started. The second email was hey approver (me) you have something to approve.

In a regular scenario, I wouldn't be the requestor, so I wouldn't see that email. Since I was testing the solution against myself before rolling it out, I was unknowingly wearing both hats.

Crisis averted!!